# UIActivityViewController identified as non-public API for my Mac Catalyst app

Tags: xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, mac-catalyst

The app runs on Mac and I can upload it using Xcode 11 with no error.
Shortly after upload, I get this messages from App Store Connect (in an email):

`ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in <xyz>: UIActivityViewController`

`UIActivityViewController` clearly is public API even for Mac Catalyst: Catalysthttps://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller

**Update**:
This issue is resolved in the latest version of Xcode (11.1)

Comment: So did you got this issue sorted out? I am trying Catalyst app, basically UIActivityViewController does not show at all.

Comment: I get only small popup (with one button "More") for Catalyst app.

Comment: I don't get that message, but I did get only the 'More' button appearing.  To fix my particular issue I had to use the #if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST and pass my image NSData as a UIImage instead.  It works fine for MacOS and iOS now.

Comment: After I share UIImage on Mac Catalyst as Add to photos, I get this exception: [xpc.exceptions] <NSXPCConnection: 0x60000302d950> connection to service on pid 15268 named com.apple.share.System.add-to-iphoto.apple-extension-service: Exception caught during decoding of received selector _completeRequestReturningItems:forExtensionContextWithUUID:completion:, dropping incoming message.
Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
Exception: value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSURL'. Allowed classes are '{(